# Stack Overflow reloading automatically every 30 seconds

Tags: bug

I'll be right in the middle of writing something, and all the Stack Overflow tabs I have open will reload at the same time. I checked the console, but I didn't see any hints. Also, this is only happening on the regular Stack Overflow - it does not happen here on Meta.

What do you recommend I do to track this issue down?

PS: I'm using Chrome, and it seems to be up to date.

Comment: start by disabling all browser extensions you have loaded

Comment: Got any plugins that might have something in them that polls/refreshes?  This wouldn't normally occur in vanilla Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

OK, thanks to @JoeW I started disabling all my Chrome extensions. I timed the reload time to about one minute, so if the page didn't reload after a minute, I knew I had disabled the correct one.

The perpetrator:
[Stack Overflow title alerter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-title-alert/bmafikmchgpknlekdllpbgelnnlkejhn?hl=en-US&gl=US)